# How can I directly get battery status in battery status in cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I tried [cordova-plugin-battery-status](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status) plugin to get my mobile current battery level. It's working fine when the battery level is changed. But I really want the status at my first call. Is there any solutions? or I should develop my app in native?